# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occured in System.Data.dll (incorrect syntax)

Tags: c#, sql, syntax-error

I can't work out what the problem is here, since the additional information comes back as: Incorrect Syntax near '('.   I think I need fresh eyes on this I can't see the error.

Here is my code, im trying to update the information to the selected Owner_ID.

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE OwnerTable SET (Owner_ID, Owner_Fname, Owner_Lname, Owner_HouseNo, Owner_Street, Owner_County, Owner_PostCode, Owner_Tele, Owner_Email) VALUES (@OwnerID, @OwnerFName, @OwnerLName, @OwnerHouseNo, @OwnerStreet, @OwnerCounty, @OwnerPostCode, @OwnerTele, @OwnerEmail) WHERE Owner_ID = @OwnerID", connection);

            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerID", CB_OWNER_ID.GetItemText(CB_OWNER_ID.SelectedItem));

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerFName", TXT_OWNER_FNAME.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerLName", TXT_OWNER_LNAME.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerHouseNo", TXT_OWNER_HOUSENO.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerStreet", TXT_OWNER_STREET.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerCounty", TXT_OWNER_COUNTY.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerPostCode", TXT_OWNER_POSTCODE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerTele", TXT_OWNER_TELE.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerEmail", TXT_OWNER_EMAIL.Text);
```

Comment: It is `set a=b, c=d`.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, ANSI SQL has `set (c1, c2) = (v1, v2)`, feature T641, "Multiple column assignment". (Supported by at least some vendors.)

Comment: But OP uses `values`, which is incorrect @jarlh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used `INSERT` syntax instead of [`UPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) syntax:

```
UPDATE OwnerTable SET Owner_ID = @OwnerID, Owner_Fname = @OwnerFName ..etc
```

---

Or if you indeed wanted to *insert* a new record change `UPDATE` to `INSERT INTO` and remove the `WHERE` (but I guess the `WHERE` indicates that you wanted to update).

Btw: are you sure to update the `OwnerID` in the `OwnerTable`? Seems wrong to me.

Comment: Thanks for this, I have got totally mixed up! You're right about the Update in OwnerTable I dont want to update the owner Id in the owner table.